# How to upload file in apollo-server using graphql file extension?

Tags: upload, graphql, apollo

I am using apollo-server 2.0 and .graphql files for my typeDefs.
I am unable to create upload feature because of using .graphql extension.
I tried to use `scalar Upload` but it is already defined by Apollo. So it does not work neither with that definition nor without it. After my research i found that i should use ``` gql`` ``` keyword to define Upload type. But my types are in .graphql files so i am unable to merge them.
What can i do ?

[[image: SS 1[1]]

[[image: SS2 [2]]

Comment: The latest version of ApolloServer supports uploads out of the box and will append the Upload scalar to your type definitions (unless you're passing it an existing schema). The fact that you're keeping the type definitions in files shouldn't matter. If uploads "aren't working" it could be for a number of reasons, like not writing your resolvers correctly or not configuring your client correctly. Please update your question with more details about what is not working, including any error messages you are seeing in either the client or the server.